# How to count all the words with special characters

Tags: php, arrays, string, word-count

I have a question about a String i want to count all the characters in the string. Like if i have a string

```
"Hello world & good morning. The date is 18.05.2016"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
<?php
 $file = "C:\Users\singh\Desktop\Talkative Challenge\base_example.txt"; 
 $document = file_get_contents($file); 
 $return_array = preg_split("/[\s,]+/",$document);
 echo count($return_array);
 echo $document;
?>
```

Hopefully it will be working fine.

Comment: Isn't preg_split a bit heavy for this simple task?

Comment: @Andreas yes it's a bit heavy, but it's work perfect what's i want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()` to convert string into array and then use `count()` function to count length of array.

```
echo count(explode(' ', "Hello world & good morning. The date is 18.05.2016"))
```

Comment: @user12195678 Is my answer is not working for your question? Please let me know about.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter of [str_word_count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) allows you to set additional characters to be counted as words:

```
str_word_count($document, 0, '&.0..9');
```

`&.0..9` means it will consider `&`, `.`, and range from `0` to `9`.

Comment: I tried this but its giving me total word count as 8 but it should be 9.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can count the spaces with substr_count and add one.

```
echo substr_count($str, " ")+1;
// 9
```

https://3v4l.org/oJJkt